# Source code for Rhino.Mocks-3.6

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

Hi I cant find the source code for Rhino.Mocks-3.6. Anyone who can help me?

The binaries can be found at http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks but no source code to be found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's located on GitHub:

https://github.com/ayende/rhino-mocks